# David Applegate conjecture at OEIS sequence A237424

Tags: nt.number-theory, oeis

The OEIS sequence is the sequence of the numbers of the form $$(10^a+10^b+1)/3$$
were $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers

Here is the link for the sequence https://oeis.org/A237424

This sequence has the property that the digits of the product of any two (not necessarily distinct terms) of it appear in nondecreasing order.
For example take $a1=0$ and $b1=1$ and $a2=5$ and $b2=5$ :

We have $(10^0+10^1+1)/3=4$ and $(10^5+10^5+1)/3=66667$

$4*66667=266668$

Professor David Applegate put a conjecture about this sequence that it is the maximally dense sequence with that nondecreasing products property

My question is divided into two parts, the first part is giving a simple explanation of Applegate conjecture that makes us understand it better, and the second part of my question is to find proof or disproof of Applegate conjecture

Thank you.